# identify a piano etude by music score of initial bars

Tags: piano, sheet-music

Please help identify a piano etude from the below score. Conventional apps (Shazam, SoundHound) seem to fail.

[image: four measure of treble clef from unknown etude]

Comment: Sorry, that kind of question [isn't covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (and I'm afraid I don't recognize it).